# Error en programa de ordenamiento con el algoritmo Merge Sort en lenguaje C

Tags: array, c, algoritmos

Tengo este programa en C que ordena 100000 números aleatorios mediante el algoritmo de Merge Sort pero no me hace el ordenamiento y no escribe en el archivo resultado2.txt. El archivo resultado3.txt son los 100000 números aleatorios. Podrían ayudarme a ver mis errores y las posibles soluciones, de antemano , muchas gracias.
El siguiente código es el main del programa, después del main viene la función del algoritmo de Merge Sort.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
void ordenarPorMezcla(int posIzq, int arregloNumeros[], int posDer);

int main(){
int i; 
char ofilename[] = "resultado2.txt";
FILE *archivo;

if((archivo = fopen(ofilename, "w"))==NULL){
printf("Error en apertura de archivo");
}

FILE * flujo=fopen("resultado3.txt", "r");
if(flujo == NULL){
    perror("error en la apertura del archivo");
    return 1;
}

fseek(flujo, 0, SEEK_SET);
int numerodeele = ftell(flujo);
rewind(flujo);

int * arregloNumeros = (int*) calloc(sizeof(int), numerodeele); 
if(arregloNumeros == NULL){
    perror("error en la reserva de memoria");
    return 2;                                                                   
}

int num_elementos_leidos = fread(arregloNumeros,sizeof(int), numerodeele, flujo);
if(num_elementos_leidos != numerodeele) {
    perror("Error leyendo el archivo");
    return 3;
}

free(arregloNumeros);
fclose(flujo);
// ordenamos por mezcla
ordenarPorMezcla(0, arregloNumeros, 100001-1);

// imprimimos el arreglo ordenado
printf("arreglo ordenado");
for( i=0; i<100001; i++)
    fprintf(archivo,"%d\n ", arregloNumeros[i]);
printf("\n");

// Hacemos una pausa para que el programa no se cierre
system("pause");

// Finalizamos el programa principal
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // fin del main
```

No agregare la función del algoritmo para no ocupar tanto espacio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fíjate en este código:

```
FILE * flujo=fopen("resultado3.txt", "r");
fseek(flujo, 0, SEEK_SET);
int numerodeele = ftell(flujo);
rewind(flujo);
```

Hace lo siguiente:

1. Abres un archivo. Al abrirlo el puntero interno apuntará **al inicio del archivo**
2. Te posicionas al inicio del archivo, es decir, **no haces nada**, ya que el puntero interno ya se encontraba en esa posición.
3. Lees... ¿La posición del puntero interno? va a ser cero.
4. Posicionas el puntero interno del fichero al inicio del mismo (...)

Es decir, las tres últimas líneas de ese algoritmo se podrían simplificar así:

```
int numerodeele = 0;
```

Entiendo que con ese algoritmo estás intentando calcular cuántos números tiene el fichero y lamento comunicarte que por esa vía, por mucho que lo intentes, no lo vas a conseguir.

Para empezar porque el fichero, independientemente de si su contenido se encuentra en modo binario o modo texto, no va a destinar un byte a cada número:

- Si se encuentra en modo binario se usarán `sizeof(int)` bytes por cada número
- Si se encuentra en modo texto se usará un byte por cada dígito de cada número más al menos otro para separar dos números (salto de línea, espacio, coma, ...)

Adicionalmente hay que tener en cuenta que `fseek` no funciona en todos los casos. Tal y como se indica en la documentación:

> For streams open in text mode, offset shall either be zero or a value returned by a previous call to ftell, and origin shall necessarily be SEEK_SET.

Es decir:

> Para *streams* abiertos en modo texto, el offset deberá ser 0 o un valor devuelto por una llamada previa a `ftell` *origin* deberá ser necesariamente `SEEK_SET`

Resumiendo, tu idea es posicionarte al final del fichero pero no puedes usar `SEEK_END` **ya que no es una operación soportada en modo texto**. Además hay que tener en cuenta que esa posición no te serviría absolutamente para nada.

¿Cómo lo podemos hacer entonces?

Una opción pasa por leer dos veces el archivo:

- En la primera pasada te centras en contar cuántos números hay. Esta operación puede ser tan sencilla como contar el número de separadores, aunque suele ser más seguro contar todos los grupos de dígitos que te encuentres.
- En la segunda pasada te limitas a leer los números.

Como hemos comentado, una forma de saber cuántos números hay es contar las agrupaciones de dígitos:

```
int c;
int grupoDigitos = 0;
int numerodeele = 0;
while( (c = fgetc(flujo)) != EOF )
{
  if( isdigit(c) )
  {
    grupoDigitos = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    numerodeele += enNumero;
    grupoDigitos = 0;
  }
}
fseek(flujo, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

La lectura de los números también parece tener problemas y el motivo es que los estás leyendo **como si estuviesen en binario**. No es lo mismo tener un número en binario (que ocupará normalmente 4 bytes) a tenerlo en modo texto (lo que viene siendo legible por el humano común), en cuyo caso cada número ocupará un número diferente de bytes.

Si vas a usar los mecanismos de lectura a bajo nivel te toca recomponer el número a partir de su representación, es decir, coges el primer caracter, lo conviertes en un dígito numérico y si hay más caracteres multiplicas el resultado por 10 y repites el proceso... claro que también puedes usar [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf):

```
for( int i=0; i<numerodeele; i++ )
{
  fscanf (flujo, "%d", &arregloNumeros[i]);
}
```